How to export few symbols (not all) to global symbol table while linking static library with a cpp file while creating executable
I am running python script from a cpp function. Created a main.py python script. Then created a cpp function (callPyFunc) to call another function defined in main.py, and made a static library of this cpp function. Now created another program main1.cpp, included this static library and called the callPyFunc function and also defined a foo() function. While creating the executable of main1.cpp I linked  library which I created, python library, dynamic linker, math, pthread. At last I have also set a flag -rdynamic so that all the symbols exported to global symbol table by doing so my foo() function also comes into global symbol table, but I don't want it to come into global symbol table. So is there any way to export only a few symbols required or is there any way of exporting symbols of only static library.
I tried to use version script but that is for dynamic library.
I have also tried adding attributes hidden in main1.cpp that is working for me but for some reason I don't want to go with this option.

Please, can you provide minimum_reproducible_code?

There are a number of ways to handle this.

From the C++ (and C) side of things, free functions tagged static in a file are not exported to the symbol table. (They are local to the file).
int exported()
{
  // this function gets exported by default
}

static int internal()
{
  // this function does not get exported by default
}

This is my preferred solution, since it is built in to the language.
I do not know what limitations exist with C++ classes. (Whenever I write a shared library, I make sure the ABI is C-compatible, even if it is backed by C++ constructs.)

GCC allows you to do a couple of other things as well. The first is by a combination of command-line option and attribute.
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
int exported()
{
  // this function gets exported by default
}

int internal()
{
  // this function does not get exported by default
}

Compile with g++ ... -shared -fPIC -visibility=hidden to make all symbols hidden except for those explicitly marked with the “default“ attribute in the source code.
I do not like this option, because it is weirdo-compiler-specific stuff goobering the source code. If you only intend to target GCC, though, it is fine. (Otherwise you’ll need the traditional #ifdef/macro muck to select between compilers somewhere.)

The final GCC-specific trick is to use a LD Version Script.
Create a file that looks something like:
LIBFOO_1.0 {
  global:
    exported;

  local:
    *;
};

This file says that exported is an exported symbol (just list all exported symbols separated by semicolons), but everything else (*) is local, i.e. not exported.
Compile with the linker option: g++ ... -shared -fPIC -Wl,--version-script=SCRIPTFILE (where “SCRIPTFILE” is the name of your version script file).
This is a nicer way to do it because other compilers (like MSVC) have similar features (though they are implemented in a different way, of course).

P.S. I did not know much about GCC-specific options. I learned about them following Antek’s tech blog.

Should I make this a community answer? Anyone could improve it.

Due to some limitations of the project I don't want to use attribute "hidden" method. And another method you suggest that is version script, I believe that is for shared library not for static library.  Static keyword will restrict the symbol from going into the global symbol table but i am looking for something like we can export only few symbols to global symbol table and rest of the symbol will not get exported.

I missed the part where you indicated that your library is static (sorry), but the version script should work either way. Shared or static, the library’s export table can be controlled by that script.
